# node js sending data to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webbrowser-control

So to keep it simple I would like to know how to use node js and a web browser.
I know how to open one using that snippet below.

```js
var open = require("open"); 
open('127.0.0.1:1337');
```

But how would I change the URL in the browser in node js? Or gathering data that is on the site? Such as sending the html code to the node js server or sending the node js server the current connected web sockets. So the node js server can do anything a normal user can.

Comment: I don't know what you're up to... but it sounds to me that Silenium Webdriver would make your life more easy ;)

Comment: I'm making a server-side bot for a browser game. What is Silenium Webdrive? @Pika

Comment: silenium webdriver basically is a great plugin for interacting with webpages - i think most of the functionality you're lookin for is inside

Comment: Thanks @Pika that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/en/index.html) to create URL. [This](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) should help you create url and send data to browser